# repository docker.wso2.com/wso2is not found

Tags: wso2

When I try to use WSO2 docker it gives an error.
Please see the following commands and responses:

```
[oracle@ol75new ~]$ docker login docker.wso2.com

Username: baterdene.m@gmail.com

Password:

Login Succeeded

[oracle@ol75new ~]$ docker run -it -p 9443:9443 docker.wso2.com/wso2is

Unable to find image 'docker.wso2.com/wso2is:latest' locally

docker: Error response from daemon: repository docker.wso2.com/wso2is not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull the docker image from docker.wso2.com, you need to have a valid subscription. These docker images will be available in the docker hub soon. For the moment, you can build the docker image from https://github.com/wso2/docker-is